# How to make flashing lights in Minecraft with repeaters?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

What is the best circuits for flashing lights with repeaters ? I've seen old school way with redstone but now with the repeaters, how to do it right ?

Comment: Before I answer the question, are you referring to a row of flashing lights, or simply how to make one Redstone Torch oscillate on and off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Redstone, there isn't really a right or wrong way to do anything. Here is one simple technique you can use to create flashing lights.

In this image, the part of the circuit at the bottom is known as a clock. It switches the Redstone Torch connected to the block from the on and off position. When the torch is off, no power is sent to the repeaters. This allows the torch to turn on. Then, the "on signal" travels through the repeaters and turns off the torch. This pattern repeats infinitely.

The signal is then sent to the repeaters in the hole I made. When power is sent through the repeaters, the block in front of them becomes "powered". This turns off the Redstone Torches mounted on each of those blocks, and in turn, alternates the Redstone Torches on the surface on and off.

[image]

Comment: There are at least a few wrong ways to do it...

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
B = a block of whatever
W = redstone wire on the ground
T = A redstone torch
R = repeater

TB  <- torch connected to the side of the block
RW
WW
```

[image]

Comment: Did not worked!

Comment: @Warface Did you orient the repeater the correct way? The signal should be flowing from the Redstone Torch *into* the Redstone Dust.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is using redstone lamps you can wire it up in a complete circle say around the roof of a building, with the lamps in the corners of the building. You wire it up in this row and in the middle there is a circle of redstone and redstone repeaters. You break the redstone on the right bottom hand side and place a redstone torch and then immediately break the torch and place down the redstone dust. This in turn (as long as you've wired it up correctly) make a circuit that is in a repeating pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can shift click two hoppers so they are pointing to each other and put 1 block in one of the hoppers. Then a comparator coming off with repeaters after that to delay it.

Answer (score 0):

use a redstone clock so that every _ ticks it turns on. This causes "flickering"

Comment: Can you expand on that? This is a very meager answer. Also, the OP is asking for solutions involving repeaters.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy just:
- Place two Repeaters right next to each other, facing opposite directions. 
- Connect them using Redstone.
- Choose any spot of Redstone as your output, and have it go over the lights and place a lever somewhere with Redstone.
- Flick it on and then off extremely quickly and you have the flashing lights (it may takes a couple of tries depending on what tick you have the Repeaters on).
Be sure to keep both Repeaters on the same tick.